# Ruby on Rails - Best way to run one time scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

We have to fix some bad data on our production app in order to add a null constraint in the DB.

I know one way to do it is to create a migration and run the script in there, but it feels wrong to take that approach because I need to access models and those model names can change throughout the life of the app, breaking migrations when run from start to finish.

I've thought about a rake task but rake tasks feel like they're meant to be run more than once.

I really just need a place to keep record of the script, but after searching for answers I didn't see any suggestions about putting these into a special folder in the app.

Would love to hear thoughts on this and which approach makes the most sense.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably go with something like `bin/repair_db`.

Comment: do you need to change the database structure or just change the data only?

Comment: Just the data. One time shot

Answer (score 3):

I think you can totally use a rake task to fix bad data. A rake task can be use once or many times depend on your needs. You can delete the rake task after using it. Rake tasks also are widely used in our project.

Comment: Yeah I'm not super against using a rake task. We just have so many ones that we actually use often, I just didn't want to bloat our list of tasks. Thanks for the answer though! I posted the solution I went with

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to change the data in `production`

- SSH into you production environment
- CHDir to your current deployment dir open `Rails Console` in `--sandbox` mode See here for more detail about rails console
  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console
- Apply the changes you desire and verify the changes if it is as you expected
- if it is as you expected, type all the commands in notepad with `;` at the end  of every statement or proper `line-feed`
- After that copy all the commands at once..
- open Rails console in normal mode and execute the commands at once

> **Rails console in Sandbox mode:** Any changes you make is rolled back after you exit the console.
>   And, Changing data in `production` without verifying properly could cost you a fortune. so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with a migration, except I'm skipping over the code to fix data if the class doesn't exist anymore.

Reason why I ended up going with a migration is because some other developers on my team will need the fixed data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the next concept about one-time scripts in rails.

1. Create all new scripts in `./scripts/adhoc/[task-prefix].rb`;
2. Run it like: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails runner script/adhoc/TASK_100500.rb`;

You are will be able to access all rails classes from that scripts.

It's all!